Can Stemming be applied before Regexp in Sphinx Config?
I usually keep Stemming off in Sphinx Search since, for me, it causes more problems than it solves.
However in my current scenario I need to turn it on.  The problem is it does not seem to implement it prior to any RegexP mapping.
So if I map e.g
RegexP_Filter=Term=>Word

Then Term and Word will find one another (since both search as Word).
And Term and Words will find one another since both are still searching for Word.
However Terms fails as it searches on Terms.
So clearly when I mapped Term it was not Stemmed.
I get I can do
Regexp_Filter=Terms?=>Word but that adds a whole layer of effort and potential given the number of suffix alterations between plural types (e.g. ies') and adjectives (ial) and the whole purpose of turning Morph on was to save work not add work.
I know there are Wordforms and Exceptions but those, as far as I know, are ignored by Stemming not processed as well. Is there a file/way to Stem before doing further manual mapping?
